# Restrict the resizing of div on browser resize

Tags: html, css

I have a website in which the layout look something like the following:

[image]

The css for the `main` content is as follows:

```
.home {margin:178px 0 0 100px;width:800px;padding:0 10px 0px 10px;float:left;height:auto!important;height:310px;min-height:310px;}
```

The problem is whenver I resize the browser, the main content div instead of staying there and the browser getting horizontal scrollbars
moves down automatically.

If I resize the browser back to its original size, the main div doesn't even come back to its original place. How do I correct this thing?

Comment: put the html and css on jsfiddle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Add the two elements (left,right) inside a `container div`, and give this container a `min-width`**

```
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      min-width:750px;
      min-height:500px;
    }
    div.container {
      min-width:600px;
      min-height:450px;
    }
    div.left, div.right {
      min-height:400px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: No. Min-width specifies the minimum width the element can be.

Comment: **min-width**, as the name suggests means that the specified html element should always have **atleast that much width, whatever the size of screen may be**

Comment: Yes, I adjusted the `min-wdith` of the `.home` div to be 800px but now it goes down the sidebar with a width of 800px. The problem is it's still doing down

Comment: Please mark it as the answer :D do not just upvote, if another user googles this good question, he will only find upvote, not a green tick :)

Comment: Yes, but I don't understand how does this solve the problem? The div is still going down even thought the width increases and that's what my original question was

Comment: The `css` in the my post shows that the `.home` element has a `float:left`

Comment: **I HAVE EDITED MY ANSWER**, the concept is if height of screen is reduced/increasing, and if left element (floated) is shorter than right element, it can get under it, something like that

Comment: Please avoid using Caps. That sends across a impolite sentiments. Secondly, I really do not understand what you are trying to do and why would the left element move under something? On a web pages, the sidebar and the content div should be adjacent, not above/below each other as in the context of this question

Comment: This is what I said, I will repeat: 'if you have floated sidebar, only a height of 100% will not let anything come under it when screen resizes' this is also possible if you give the sidebar a min-height of 600px or more

Answer (score 0):

This is two column full screen layout with [colorized column background](http://www.ejeliot.com/blog/61) (if necessary) & [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalatino/hBDqg/):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
html,body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  height:100%;
  background-color:#ccc;
}

#header {
  background-color:#ccf;
}

#container {
  position:relative;
  min-height:80%;
  border:4px solid red;
  overflow:hidden;
}

#left {
  float:left;
  width:200px;
  background-color:#cfc;
  padding-bottom:9999px;
  margin-bottom:-9999px;
}

#main {
  position:relative;
  margin-left:200px;
  background-color:#ffc;
  padding-bottom:9999px;
  margin-bottom:-9999px;
}

#footer {
  background-color:#fcc;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">HEADER</div>
<div id="container">
  <div id="left">LEFT</div>
  <div id="main">MAIN</div>
  <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
<div id="footer">FOOTER</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The core of this solution is: the `#left` div is floated to left and the `#main` div is not floated, but positioned either as relative or static element. So that the divs cannot be wrongly recounted and displaced when resizing the browser, as it is nicely [explained in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11973556/gap-in-percentage-based-layout/11973891#11973891).