# gap in percentage based layout

Tags: css, responsive-design

I'm having a problem with percentage based layout. Here is my code http://jsfiddle.net/uHkXH/

If your are using Safari or Opera on Mac, or IE7 on Windows, or iPhone iPad you will see a gap on the right side. But the width, padding and margin of four boxes should be 100% in total. I cannot understand why there is still a gap.

Does anyone can explain this problem and help me to solve it? Thank you very much indeed!

Comment: If my answer has helped you please mark it as correct answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its a problem with certain browsers trying to round subpixel (decimal) widths.  The percentages are converted to pixels automatically.

If you go through and add up the calculated width in pixels of the elements in your jsfiddle they don't add up to the width of your container element.

Here is some more info
http://css-tricks.com/percentage-bugs-in-webkit/

and

[How do I get around the IE CSS percentage rounding problem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084469/how-do-i-get-around-the-ie-css-percentage-rounding-problem)

and

> > Hi,
>
> I don't have exact details of what browsers do but I have noted the
>   following in the past.
>
> When dealing width Pixels:
>
> Firefox will round 125.5px up to 126px and 125.4px will be rounded
>   down to 125px.
>
> Opera will treat 126.9px as 126px (but it will treat 126.999 as 127px
>   !!)
>
> IE ignores all the decimal points and treats 126.9999px as 126px.
>
> When dealing with percentages.
>
> Opera doesn't seem to take any notice at all of the decimal portion of
>   percentages. e.g 33.9% will only equate to exactly 33%. Therefore
>   for three floats of 33.333% in a 1000px width Opera will show a 10px
>   gap at the right edge.
>
> Mozilla seems to keep a running total of the decimal parts of
>   percentages used and will at the most only be 1 pixel out on the full
>   width.
>
> IE rounds each portion up or down individually and therefore for three
>   floats will possibly be 3 pixels too big thus causing a float drop.
>
> To stop the floats dropping in ie you can apply a negative right
>   margin to the last float that will soak up the extra space.
>   (margin-right:-3px).
>
> For opera there is no cure but perhaps to make the last element fit
>   the space required or to make the elements bigger than needed and
>   apply a larger right negative margin.
>
> This is the reason that most people simply use 33% because then they
>   know it will fit all browsers even if there is a slight gap which
>   depending on the situation may not be noticable. (e.g. the background
>   color of the element behind may hide it.)

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining! I am fully understanding now. Sorry for the late reply.